# HERE api - get map center

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm new with HERE API (still testing it)
I have 2 questions:

1. I have number of pins on the map. Can you script find automatically the center of the pins locations
2. For each pin I have div box with info (each div have unique ID). can I click on the pin and the page will scroll to the right div/position?
   see example here with google map:
   http://www.followmyroutes.com/index.php?page=itinPage&itinID=16

Regards,

Roi

Comment: Answered the first question below. Could you split the second point to another question, as it relates to a rather different matter?

Answer (score 1):

Zooming to a set of markers is easy. The idea is to use the method `setViewBounds` on the map instance.

```
// some examples marker
var toronto = new H.map.Marker({lat:43.7,  lng: -79.4});
var boston = new H.map.Marker({lat:42.35805, lng: -71.0636}),
var washington = new H.map.Marker({lat:38.8951, lng: -77.0366}),

// a group object to contain the markers
var group = new H.map.Group();

// add markers to the group
group.addObjects([toronto, boston, washington]);

// add the group to the map instance
map.addObject(group);

// get geo bounding box for the group and zoom into it
map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());
```